# MDBootstrap (material design for bootstrap) conflicting versions of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, version-control, mdbootstrap

I had a react project then later I added MDB (material design for bootstrap). But I got when using MDB

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Then I ran `npm ls react` and got

```
client@0.1.0 /home/path/to/project/client
├─┬ mdbreact@4.27.0
│ └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.14.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@17.0.1
```

So it looks like I have 2 versions of react. Similar result when I run `npm ls react-dom`

How do i fix this problem?